# Missing org.eclipse.ui.workbench plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing an Eclipse plugin... I need to make it dependant on org.eclipse.ui.workbench (i see this dependency in some sample plugins i've got imported, and works well), however if i press "add" under the "Dependencies" tab on my plugin.xml editor, it finds:

org.eclipse.ui.workbench.compatibility.source
org.eclipse.ui.workbench.source
org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor
org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.source

But there's no org.eclipse.ui.workbench plugin at all... As i said above, i've got sample plugins correctly working with that dependency. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depend on **org.eclipse.ui**, which is the main workbench plugin that exports API and schema for extension points.  No one is supposed to directly depend on **org.eclipse.ui.workbench**, you get it for free when using **org.eclipse.ui**.